# iOS - Setting block to block directly does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

The title says it, I'd like to ask why the following does not work, as it should imho.

```
// ViewController.m
#import "B.h"
...

@implementation ViewController
{
    B *bInstance;
}

- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])
    {
        bInstance = [[B alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
        [bInstance setBlockCalled:^(NSDictionary *dict) {
            NSLog(@"%@", dict[@"key"]);
        }];

        [self.view addSubview:bInstance];
    }
    return self;
}


// B.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface B : UIView
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^blockCalled)(NSDictionary *);
@end

// B.m
#import "B.h"
#import "A.h"

@implementation B
{
    A *aInstance;
    void (^blockCalled)(NSDictionary *);
}

@synthesize blockCalled;

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
    {
        aInstance = [[A alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [aInstance setBlockCalled:blockCalled];

        [self addSubview:aInstance];
    }
    return self;
}

@end


// A.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface A : UIView

@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^blockCalled)(NSDictionary *);

@end

// A.m
#import "A.h"

@implementation A
{
    void (^blockCalled)(NSDictionary *);
}

@synthesize blockCalled;

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
    {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self addSubview:button];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) buttonClicked
{
    blockCalled(@{@"key":@"value"});
}

@end
```

What I want to do is 'traverse up the view hiearchy', and as far as I see it, I'm assigning a block variable with the same arguments, so I'd expect it to work. Any reason why this is a wrong idea?

EDIT: added more complete example as of when this issue might happen.

EDIT2: added MCVE, which I've tested.

After I've checked the MCVE, the code crashes on the line `blockCalled(@{@"key":@"value"});` in A.m because the blockCalled is nil.

**Updated question:** I'd like to know why calling `[aInstance setBlockCalled:blockCalled]` doesn't set the blockCalled in A, as it seems to me to be the same as

```
[aInstance setBlockCalled:^(NSDictionary *dict) 
{ 
    __strong typeof (self) strongSelf = self; 
    strongSelf.blockCalled(dict); 
}];
```

Comment: I've added more code to complete the example, thank you for the note. Note that this is definitely not an issue with the block variable being nil. Also, I've kept the `@synthesize` and ivars, as for `A` class they are definitely part of the question, and for `B` they show that another class, perhaps called `C`, might access the block of `B` the same way `B` access the block of `A`, continuing to traverse.

Comment: This is still not enough code to reproduce the crash. Show not just `A` and `B`, but how you use them that results in a crash. There are problems here (see answer below), but there's not enough evidence here to know whether one of these issues is the culprit, or whether there is some other issue stemming from code not included here. But, again, the ivar and `@synthesize` statement are not only unnecessary, but inadvisable, too.

Comment: @Rob thanks for the comment. I've updated the question once again; I'd like to ask for a source for the statement that 'the ivar and `@synthesize` statement are not only unnecessary, but inadvisable, too.', if you'd be so kind.

Comment: The reason it's inadvisable is that you can make a typo in the ivar name and never know it because the compiler will then synthesize an ivar of the correct name, and you now have two ivars floating around. I think the general observation about the fact that you should no longer synthesize and declare your ivars would be discussed in either of the two Modern Objective-C [WWDC 2012 videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    B *bInstance;
}

- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])
    {
        bInstance = [[B alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
        [bInstance setBlockCalled:^(NSDictionary *dict) {
            NSLog(@"%@", dict[@"key"]);
        }];

        [self.view addSubview:bInstance];
    }
```

At the moment of initializing `bInstance`, you haven't set the block yet. It means

```
aInstance = [[A alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[aInstance setBlockCalled:blockCalled];
```

is called before

```
[bInstance setBlockCalled:^(NSDictionary *dict) {
    NSLog(@"%@", dict[@"key"]);
}];
```

You should override the block setter in B and call it on A.

```
// B.m
-(void)setBlockCalled(void(^)(NSDictionary*))passedBlock{
      [a setBlockCalled:passedBlock];
}
```

Comment: Hey Mercurial! You're right on spot, that's the issue. Thanks for the explanation and a possible solution; I thought that blocks might behave the same way as array do, being passed around as pointer rather than value. Do you know how the example might be changed (perhaps by modifying some attributes of the block) so that the blocks would behave as pointers (which would mean that the example would work, I think) ?

Comment: The key point here is that your property is declared as copy. That's why the value is passed instead of the pointer. Block is an object, and you can declare it as strong/weak just as you declare any other obj-c object. I suggest you check out the official properties documentation(it's called encapsulating data IIRC).

Comment: I'll do that, and I'll also try to get rid of that `copy` thing, as I don't like it anymore. Thanks!

Comment: Blocks should always be `copy` properties. See [Working with Blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW12) says "Note: You should specify copy as the property attribute, because a block needs to be copied to keep track of its captured state outside of the original scope. This isn’t something you need to worry about when using ARC, as it will happen automatically, but it’s best practice for the property attribute to show the resultant behavior."

Comment: Thanks for the note. Does that mean that the wanted behavior (to set the pointer to the block rather than a value) is not possible with pure obj-c blocks, at least not in the init methods?

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question (a) uses ivars and `@synthesize` statements that are unnecessary; and (b) this code snippet is insufficient to reproduce the crash you describe.

Having said that, there are two possible source of crashes that are suggested by the code sample in the question, namely: (a) the code fails to remove the observer if `A` is deallocated; and (b) it really should double-check to make sure that blocks are non-nil before trying to call them.

But, consider the following:

```
// A.h

@interface A : UIView
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^blockCalled)(NSDictionary *dict);
@end

// A.m

@implementation A

- (instancetype) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNotification:) name:@"kNotification" object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // never just call `blockCalled`; always check to see if not null

    if (self.blockCalled) {
        // everything is good, so let's call the block

        self.blockCalled(notification.userInfo);
    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
    // never just `addObserver`; make sure to remove the observer when this is deallocated

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"kNotification" object:nil];
}

@end

// B.h

@interface B : UIView
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^blockCalled)(NSDictionary *dict);
@property (nonatomic, strong) A *aInstance;
@end

// B.m
@implementation B

- (void) someMethod {
    // !!!!! why this crashes the app when blockCalled on aInstance is called:
    [self.aInstance setBlockCalled:self.blockCalled];

    // but this does not crash when the same happens
    __weak typeof (self) weakSelf = self;

    self.aInstance.blockCalled = ^(NSDictionary *dict) {
        __strong typeof (self) strongSelf = weakSelf;

        // again, never just call `blockCalled`; always check to see if not null

        if (strongSelf.blockCalled) {
            strongSelf.blockCalled(dict);
        }
    };
}

@end
```

Bottom line, when I fix the two obvious sources of crashes (failing to remove observer and failing to check to make sure the block was non-nil before calling it), and test it with logical scenario, it seems to work fine:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    B *b = [[B alloc] init];
    b.blockCalled = ^(NSDictionary *dict) {
        NSLog(@"%@", dict);
    };
    A *a = [[A alloc] init];
    b.aInstance = a;
    [b someMethod];

    [self.view addSubview:a];
    [self.view addSubview:b];

    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"foo": @"bar", @"baz": @"qux"};
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"kNotification" object:nil userInfo:dict];
}
```

So, assuming one of these two issues wasn't the source of the problem, you must provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can use to reproduce the crash you describe.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. The crash disappears when I add the  `if (blockCalled)` check before calling the block, but the question remains pretty much the same. Please see updated question.

Comment: Above you said "Note that this is definitely not an issue with the block variable being nil." Well, if the problem was fixed by adding `if (blockCalled)` then it absolutely _is_ a result of `blockCalled` being `nil`. And that's undoubtedly a result of the sequence that you're doing these steps, as Mercurial said. BTW, that discussion about `copy` v `strong` is a red herring.